# gradle dependencies - приложение не видит подтянутые зависимости

Tags: java, gradle, зависимости

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "application"

mainClassName = "com.example.Main"

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "log4j:log4j:1.2.17"
}

jar {
    manifest.attributes("Main-Class": mainClassName);
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = "1.12"
}
```

Main.java

```
package com.example;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Main {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LOG.info("Application started");

        System.out.println("main project");

    }
}
```

Этот код собирается в jar-файл, и при запуске `java -jar build/libs/main_project.jar` выходит ошибка что не найден класс Logger:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/log4j/Logger   at com.example.Main.(Main.java:7)

В jar-файл не ложатся зависимости. Но если перейти в cd build/classes/main/, и оттуда выполнить java com.example.Main то все-равно ошибка что не найден класс.

В таком случае - зачем нужны dependecies, если мы их нигде не можем использовать? Как запустить мой код?

Answer (score 1):

вы сначала пакуйте в отдельный jar файл БЕЗ каких либо зависимостей. поэтому ловите NoClassDefFoundError. Вам надо паковать со всеми зависимостями

```
//create a single Jar with all dependencies
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File Example',  
            'Implementation-Version': version,
            'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

выполнить  `gradle fatJar`

Comment: Заработало. Но. Для чего тогда мы подтягиваем dependencies, если в итоге все-равно их заюзать не можем без специального таска?

Comment: gradle - система сборки. она отвечает немного за другие вещи. если вам нужно собрать толскый синглтон пакет - то мой ответ один из путей. обычно делают так, чтобы ваше приложение подтянула нужные зависимсоти из classpath

Comment: В блоке dependencies я ставлю не compileOnly, а compile. Compile - скомпилирует зависимость и положит куда-то бинарник зависимости. CompileOnly - попросит компилятор не ругаться, но бинарник зависимости в сборку ложить не будет. Этим вроде и отличаются compile от compileOnly. А если так, то почему я все равно не могу заюзать класс зависимости?

Comment: по той же самой причине, что я написал в первом комменте

Comment: значит, хоть compile, хоть compileOnly, результат будет один и тот же. Получу бинарник только своих классов, но не зависимостей. В обоих случаях я смогу передать --classpath библиотека_зависимости, и будет работать